# Java signed byte usage in c# application

Tags: java, c#, data-structures, byte

I have data in bytes generated from a Java applet. Since java uses signed bytes but in another application which is in C# I have to use those bytes. For that I want to convert those signed bytes to unsigned. My Question is, does this changing of sign changes the data?

I am using this method for conversion.

```
public static int unsignedToBytes(byte b) {
   return b & 0xFF;
 }

public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(unsignedToBytes((byte) -12));
```

}

Comment: How are you trying to use the bytes? You normally just don't need to worry - the bits represented will be the same... it's only an issue at all if you treat them as *numbers*.

Comment: the bytes come from a scanner. I have to decode them to Base64 to sent to web service in a the dot Net framework. and when I decode back using C# FromBase64() method it is giving wrong values for the signed (negetive bytes).

Comment: No, it's giving you the right values in terms of bits. You've still preserved the correct data... it's just showing as a different numeric representation. For example, if you save both byte arrays to disk (Java and C#) then you won't be able to tell the difference.

Comment: `(byte)x` already converts to an unsigned byte when using the default compiler settings. I prefer to write it as `unchecked((byte)x)` so it works even if checked arithmetic is enabled for the project.